# How to access AD users in SharePoint 2010 Sandboxed solution?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, sandbox-solution

I am running with an issue to accessing AD users in Sandbox solution. Can anyone has idea how to do that.

I know how to do in normal SharePoint 2010 solution. But I am not able to do in the same way. :(

`UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.Current);
UserProfile up = null;

up = profileManager.GetUserProfile(LoginName);`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an article I've found that should solve your problems with the Client Object Model

[Article](http://www.rightpoint.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2011/07/13/sharepoint-online-for-office-365-people-search-using-spservices-and-jquery.aspx)

if it's possible use Full-Trust-Proxy this is a solution for you to interact with AD directly

[Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622616%28v=office.14%29.aspx)